# How to notify new members of their login details via email

Tags: members

When registering a new member in EE (either in the CP or via the front-end using an add-on such as Profile:Edit), the password fields are required. So how do I go about emailing the login details to a new member if I can't (and shouldn't) include the password itself in the new member registration email?

I feel like there should be a way (unless there's something I'm missing) to include an activation link in the email that would allow the user to activate their account and immediately set their password on the first login.

Is this possible, or has anyone got any tips on the best way of emailing new users with their login details?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at Postmaster v1.2, which brings Profile:edit compatibility into the mix.

https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/hooks/profile-register-end

You can send an email with the register and edit tags along with the user's password. Not sure if there is a way to do this natively with Profile:edit, but I know Postmaster works.

Comment: This is the site that I have Postmaster on, but I've not upgraded my 1.2 beta to the official 1.2 release yet so that explains why I couldn't find this hook. One thing though - I don't want to send emails on every edit, only when a new member is registered. You have a hook in your docs for Profile:Edit Profile Register, but the link goes to Profile:Edit Profile Edit page (though the label on the page calls it End, rather than Edit). Is there definitely a hook there for Register?

Comment: I will fix the typo in the docs. 100% sure the registration hook is there, I added it late last week.

Answer (score 5):

If we create an account for a user, generally staff member for the client, we've create just a basic email auto response, that we send them that includes the link to the password reset page. So the email typically looks like:

```
Dear {screen_name}-

You've been recommended for access to edit, modify, and or create content for the '{client}' website. We've created an account for you, but you'll need to reset your password to login.

To reset your password please visit:

      • http://clientdomain.org/staff/reset (appropriate link to password reset)

The email address used is listed below, as well as other necessary account details.

Your account information follows:

     Username: {username}
     Email:  {email}
     Screen Name: {screen_name}

Once your password has been reset, you can login from this link.

      • http://clientdomain.org/admin.php (link to control panel)

Please bookmark it for quick access or save this email for a record of the details.

Blah, blah, blah…

{Web Development}
```

The issue we had was that any password we provided to them was never reset, so it was easier to force the reset as requirements for logging in. So far it works and it means we can generate the same password for all the accounts we create because we know it will be reset.

Comment: Thanks for this. This seems like the best native solution to go for in a working situation.

Answer (score 4):

**[MX Notify Control](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control)** may do what you need. I haven't used it myself but it seems to allow for emailing usernames/passwords.

> The MX Notify Control extension allows you to send customized notifications by emails/PMs based on different triggers - new entry creating/updating, member registration, member validation etc..

It has a sister addon called [**MX Auto Password**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-auto-password) for generating secure member passwords.

> MX Auto Password helps you generate secure password for members during member registration and CP member registration.

Comment: I hadn't noticed MX Auto Password so I'll check it out, thanks. I'm already using Postmaster on the particular site I'm asking about though, so now that Justin has pointed out the Profile:Register hooks, I'll likely go with that on this occasion to save installing any extra add-ons.

Comment: Sounds like Postmaster will work perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Despite its claims in the docs, I was never able to get MX Notify Control to work with sending users their passwords.

However, another nice option is Eric Lamb's Securit:ee which can be configured to send an activation email and change password link to new users via the custom template of your choice. This is handy for newly imported users or sites with manual registration and approval processes. Admins can tie into newly "Activated" users and send details. This worked well for me on a project with existing members who were imported into the site with no knowledge of their passwords. Plus, you get all the added site benefits of Securit:ee, (which are many).